# while editing the table with bind, but only some columns error is returned

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

this is the model:

```
public class Test
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Serial{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

on the edit with the post

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Test test)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(test).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(test);
    }
```

if you notice there is no **Serial** bind on edit post so I get ther serial blank or empty

Comment: Can you also post the error?

Comment: Because your `BindAttribute` specifically excludes property `Serial` from binding - just remove it (all properties are bound by default)

Comment: Or if you not editing the value of `Serial` you can always include a hidden input for it, but preferably you should be using a view model,and then get the original data model in the POST method (based on the ID), update it, then save it.

Comment: there is no error it will just delete the serial

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't want the serial to come even from hidden from the view

Comment: Then do it as per my 2nd comment. Create a `TextVM` class with property  `int ID` and `string Name` (you should always use a view model, especially when editing data in a view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Serial")] Test test)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tests.Attach(test); //Tests is your controller i guess
            db.Entry(test).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(test);
    }
```